# Efficiently calculate and store similarity matrix

Tags: python, loops, matrix, pearson

For a recommender-system project in class I am currently trying to build and store an item-based similarity matrix for a dataset with about 7000 users (rows) and 4000 movies (columns). So what I have is a pivot table with UserIDs as index, MovieIDs as columns and the ratings as values. As you can imagine there are a lot of 0-ratings.

Currently I am using the pearsonr function from the scipy package. I figured that in order to store all distances I have to calculate the pearson coefficient between all columns and store them in a symmetric movie-movie matrix. My code up until now (as you can see I am new to Python/coding):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

pd.read_csv('data.csv')
data = data.pivot(index = 'UserID', columns = 'MovieID', values = "Rating")

similarity_data = pd.DataFrame(index=data.columns, columns=data.columns)

for i in range(0,len(data.columns)):
    for j in range(0,len(data.columns)):
        similarity_data.iloc[i,j] =  pearsonr(data.iloc[:,i],data.iloc[:,j])[0]
```

Well, as you can imagine this takes forever and I'm eager to find out how to do this more efficiently. My first idea was to take advantage of the matrix being symmetric. But I couldn't figure out how.

My idea was something like:

```
for i in range(0,len(data.columns)):
    for j in range(0,len(data.columns)):
        similarity_data.iloc[i,j] =  pearsonr(data.iloc[:,i],data.iloc[:,j+i])[0]
        similarity_data[j,i] = similarity_data.iloc[i,j]
```

However, even if I would get this to work, I fear that the problem here are the two for loops. I was trying to somehow use a map or lambda approach, but couldn't get anywhere.

Any idea how to improve this (probably lots of them)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll definitely want to use `np.corrcoef`, which will be about 1000 times faster than a naive loop over `scipy.stats.pearsonr`. For example:

```
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# make some small data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 40))

C1 = np.array([[pearsonr(df[i], df[j])[0] for i in df] for j in df])
C2 = np.corrcoef(df.values.T)
np.allclose(C1, C2)
# True
```

Here are the times:

```
%timeit np.array([[pearsonr(df[i], df[j])[0] for i in df] for j in df])
10 loops, best of 3: 154 ms per loop

%timeit np.corrcoef(df.values.T)
10000 loops, best of 3: 116 µs per loop
```

Still, your result will be a dense matrix with about 16 million entries, so it's not going to be a fast computation. You might think about whether you really need to store all those values, or whether you can use an algorithm that (for example) just computes the correlations of nearest neighbors.

Comment: You are right, I feel quite dumb now. This took about 5 seconds and from what I can see the result is pretty much the same. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't `np.corrcoef(data)` give you the same correlation matrix?

If not, you should be able to roughly double the performance by only calculating one half of the symmetric result matrix and not calling `pearsonr()` at all when `i` is equal to `j`.

Comment: Yes you are right, thank you. However, for the movie-based similarities i need `np.corrcoef(data.T)`. After reading your secomd comment I also figured out, that I can just set the range of the second loop to start at i. Sometimes it is really not that hard. Thank you for your reply!